# Time reversal differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a initial value problem given by: 
$$x'=f(t,x(t)) \ \ \ \ \ \ x(t_0) = x_0$$
I have to show that changing to the time variable $y = 2t_0 -t$ gives an equivalent initial value problem, given by $$v'(y) = g(y,v(y)) \ \ \ \ \ \ v(t_0) = x_0$$

How can I show why this holds? And more important, why does this hold? Because what will the solutions do if we change the time variable $t$ to such an $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to see what would work... You have $x(t)= x(2t_0 - y)$ and therefore

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = - \frac{dx}{dy}$$

Based on that, naming $v(y) = x(2t_0-y)$, you get

$$-v^\prime(y) = f(2t_0-y,v(y)).$$

So taking $g(y,v) = -f(2t_0-y,v)$, you're done as $v(2t_0 - t_0) = x(t_0) = x_0$.